# Problem apt-get update google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I am with this problem in `apt-get update`

```
W : http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg : Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm ( SHA1 )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix apt: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1) after installing Chrome?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error. It's a warning.

It says that Google uses weak security and encryption - and there's nothing you can do about it.

Your packages will still be updated.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install Chrome?

Try to delete all the sources of Google Chrome from /etc/apt/sources.list and from the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Then try to download and install the package from here:
https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

In Ubuntu just double click and install with the software center.