# Red triangle with an exclamation mark Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, ppa

so I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and the red exclamation mark just appeared.
What can I do??

[image]

---

[image]

but everything is up to date on the computer

here's what I get, when I use the update/upgrade command:

`Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable InRelease

Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release

Hit:4 http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease

Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release [1,347 B]

Get:6 http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [93.3 kB]

Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb stable Release.gpg [198 B]

Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [92.2 kB]

Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://am.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease

Fetched 187 kB in 1s (169 kB/s)

Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release  No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release which is considered strong enough for security purposes
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: Could you add to the question a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @Danibix **done**

Comment: click it. What does it say?

Comment: In the launcher bar on the left  have you got the new 'Ubuntu Software' item ? (Not to be confused with old 'Ubuntu Software Centre', which if you upgraded to get 16.04, came from an older Ubuntu version and has the same design of icon) If you have the new  'Ubuntu Software', click it and select the 'Updates' tab, click it and see what's available.

Comment: You have installed `chrome` in some strange way, without the required security keys. I would advise to uninstall chrome and the installing it again (the same for this "talkplugin" that I do not know).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix apt: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1)

Answer (score 2):

It could be an error relative to some broken updates.

You can try to fix this error updating package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*Note*: before run the above commands check that your computer is connected to internet.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: it says:  E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Releas

Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @Tatev Kot Vardapetyan Are you on 32 bit or 64 bit PC?

Comment: it is 64 bt os type

Comment: @TatevKotVardapetyan You have a broken repository (or you didn't report the error correctly). please *add to your question* the full output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @TatevKotVardapetyan If the error is exactly as you pasted it here, you're missing an "e" at the end of "Releas". You will need to edit that section of your /etc/apt/sources.list either by hand or through the "software sources" options screen to add the missing letter. Then you can run "sudo apt update" again.

Comment: @Rmano done as you said..

Comment: @NickWeinberg , no, the ''e'' is not missing,  it was my mistake when pasting