# Help error apt-get

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
Atingido:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian lucid InRelease
Atingido:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                
Atingido:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease        
Atingido:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease      
Atingido:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease         
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jason-scheunemann/ppa/ubuntu lucid InRelease    
Atingido:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Atingido:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Atingido:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jason-scheunemann/ppa/ubuntu lucid Release
Obter:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jason-scheunemann/ppa/ubuntu lucid Release.gpg [316 B]
Baixados 316 B em 1s (216 B/s)   
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
W: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/dists/lucid/InRelease: Signature by key 7B0FAB3A13B907435925D9C954422A4B98AB5139 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/jason-scheunemann/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/Release.gpg: Signature by key B7A54DFD57990DE60964F52D932062C9CD30EE56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pople will be able to help you** in a much better way **if you will explain the problem in** more **detail**, like what are you expecting in the answer, Which version of Ubuntu you are using, etc . Simply putting the content of terminal in question won't help you much.

The problem with the VirtualBox source is on VirtualBox's end, but `apt-get` is just reporting the issue as a warning. This issue does not stop you from upgrading packages.

You are using `apt-get` and what you are seeing is the normal behaviour after running `update`: it performs the update but does not provide additional information.

You need to follow `sudo apt-get update` with `sudo apt-get upgrade` to see if any package upgrades are available.

The newer `sudo apt update` (notice it's just `apt`,and it's only available in Ubuntu 16.04) does provide feedback about the results.

By using `apt`, you will either see a message that

> All packages are up to date

or

> The following packages will be upgraded:

BTW your question has been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install) already. I'm just reinstating the answer.