# Ubuntu 16.04 updating Google Chrome gets weak digest and hash sum mismatch messages

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome, 16.04

So for a while now whenever I run `sudo apt-get update` I have been getting some output regarding google-chrome similar to:

```
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Which I understand means something along the lines of Google is being lazy about their package signing, and that it shouldn't impact updating, as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install). However, just today I've started getting the following additional message when updating:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have attempted to fix the hash sum mismatch as described in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error), but the problem persists. So my main question is, is this an error with Google Chrome's package repository or my own computer?

Just in case it is pertinent, here is the full output from `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1,189 B]           
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [916 B]  
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease  
Get:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,343 B]
Err:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 3,439 B in 2s (1,566 B/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Also, somewhat of a side question, how do you suppress the warning messages from `apt-get` (if you can), and is it wise to do so?

Comment: I'm not just getting warning messages though, I am getting recurring hash mismatch errors that I can't fix the way I usually do.

Comment: Don't worry. If it's really a different issue, other people won't vote as dupe. Meanwhile, hashsum mismatch is often just temp while the mirror updates. You might try again in a few hours.

Comment: Looks like they fixed the hash problem.  Just re-run your update now.