# Update problem with signiture key

Tags: apt, updates, 16.04, google-chrome

I have just updated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I started setting up by installing Google-Chrome and then went to run a sudo apt-get update again before I started installing other software, and I get the Signature key lines and it stops. So it essentially won't let me update any packages now.

```
root@DNilesh-PC:/home/nilesh# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [93.3 kB]
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]   
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Fetched 188 kB in 1s (102 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is known and has been reported: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1558331 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=596074 
[How to fix apt: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1-after-install)

is just a warning. This issue does not stop you from upgrading packages.