# reprepro: Signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Tags: apt, reprepro

I'm hosting some internal repositories using reprepro.

After the upgrade of the clients to Ubuntu 16.04, `apt-get update` gives a warning "InRelease: Signature by key ... uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)".

InRelease file starts like that:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1
```

So, reprepro has signed the InRelease file with a SHA1. How can I change it to SHA256 or SHA512?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can fix this by modifying the `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` file of the user account which will be running `reprepro` and adding this line to the file `digest-algo sha256`. All signatures made with GPG by this user will use the SHA256 digest algorithm by default, thus, signatures made by `reprepro` will be sha256, as well.

If you want to learn more about GPG, APT, and Debian packages, I wrote a comprehensive blog post about [signing and verifying Debian packages and APT repositories](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/10/28/howto-gpg-sign-verify-deb-packages-apt-repositories/) that may be helpful.

Comment: After adjusting your `gpg.conf` as described above, you may likely need to re-export existing repositories using `reprepro export $codename` to placate clients.

Comment: I haven't found any gpg.conf file in .gnupg

Comment: @Harun-Ur-Rashid, you need to run `gpg` at least once so it creates the file. You'd have to do that anyway to create and export your key.