# Not getting updates as expected

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

Does this output from `apt update` look OK?

`$ sudo apt update`

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                      
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty   InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu trusty InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu  trusty Release
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
60C58A7169778E6FB8771ADB0816950D8 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *output* from `apt update` is **ok**. One note though, the bottom line or last line that says `60C58A7169778E6FB8771ADB0816950D8 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)`. That simply is telling you *what encryption algorithm* is used for package with *id 60C58A7169778E6FB8771ADB0816950D8*.

The *SHA256* algorithm is preferred, but apart from that your **updates were ok**. The fix will come from the package owners not your system, see [here](https://juliank.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/dropping-sha-1-support-in-apt) for more details.

See [debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal) and/or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1) also.