# Hash Sum Mismatches in 18.04 on Laptop and in Docker

Tags: 18.04

I am having Hash Sum Mismatches all over the place for the past two weeks. At first I thought nothing of it, but now that they have persisted for so long, there must be an underlying problem.

I see them on my regular machine, but also when I start up a Docker container. I did not expect to see them also in the Docker container. I would have thought I simply had some configuration error on my main machine. In an attempt to solve this, I have tried various permutations of

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
sudo apt clean
```

as suggested by multiple threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083839/hash-sum-mismatch-in-ubuntu-16-04-3
- [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/)

I also made sure that I am getting updates from the `Main Server`[image]:

Any other ideas?

The output of

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt update
```

is

```
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease [21,3 kB]                                                   
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]                                                                        
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [10,2 kB]                                                                    
Get:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64,4 kB]                                                               
Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3.182 B]                                                            
Get:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner i386 Packages [2.300 B]                                                        
Get:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner amd64 Packages [2.304 B]                                                       
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                               
Get:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic/partner Translation-en [1.272 B]                                                      
Get:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [15,8 kB]                                         
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]                                                            
Get:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [96,6 kB]                                                 
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [18,8 kB]                                        
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                                                             
Get:16 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages [4.696 B]                                                  
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [5.372 B]                                        
Get:18 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Contents (deb) [1.832 B]                                            
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [1.007 kB]                                                            
Get:20 https://typora.io/linux ./ InRelease [758 B]                                                                                 
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [1.019 kB]                                     
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [516 kB]                                                             
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [477 kB]                                                      
Get:1 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease [23,5 kB]                                                 
Get:24 https://typora.io/linux ./ Packages [9.872 B]                                                                                    
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [118 kB]                                                         
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [245 kB]                                                         
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic amd64 Contents (deb) [39,5 MB]                                                           
Ign:28 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main i386 Packages                                                 
Get:29 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main amd64 Packages [9.630 B]                                      
Get:28 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie/main i386 Packages [4.991 B]                                       
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb) [38,8 MB]                                                            
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted i386 Packages [9.156 B]                                                       
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted amd64 Packages [9.184 B]                                                      
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted Translation-en [3.584 B]                                                      
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [527 kB]                                                     
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [453 kB]                                                      
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [196 kB]                                                     
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]                                              
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66,7 kB]                                                
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [123 kB]                                                 
Err:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                          
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:122730 [weak]
   - SHA256:efd861307ea8f09f87224776e01985a6dbfbcf98ee8bb6c5989a07da4db16096
   - SHA1:532fb3103b75340dee8e8817aeb536a8e3385e8b [weak]
   - MD5Sum:8e9145351f55ece4ea3958858a2bf647 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:d03f0153972054426d71cddc4f9617d4cf4d856a85dcc5cbe395df50231f46e3
   - SHA1:ce4661e73c9134be116d8c755afe7d5ce5135c69 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9ba8bd1b0b02ecd2f63b43f4f6be80ed [weak]
   - Filesize:122730 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 05:59:58 +0000
  Release file created at: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 10:44:06 +0000
Err:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates amd64 Contents (deb)                                                             

Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates i386 Contents (deb) [16,0 MB]                                                    
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6.948 B]                                               
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [6.996 B]                                              
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted Translation-en [3.076 B]                                              
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports amd64 Contents (deb) [4.254 B]                                                 
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports i386 Contents (deb) [4.252 B]                                                  
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [270 kB]                                                    
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages [203 kB]                                                     
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main Translation-en [101 kB]                                                    
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]                                              
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]                                                  
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]                                                  
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security i386 Contents (deb) [11,3 MB]                                                   
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security amd64 Contents (deb) [16,9 MB]                                                  
Fetched 129 MB in 56s (2.291 kB/s)                                                                                                      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/efd861307ea8f09f87224776e01985a6dbfbcf98ee8bb6c5989a07da4db16096  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:122730 [weak]
    - SHA256:efd861307ea8f09f87224776e01985a6dbfbcf98ee8bb6c5989a07da4db16096
    - SHA1:532fb3103b75340dee8e8817aeb536a8e3385e8b [weak]
    - MD5Sum:8e9145351f55ece4ea3958858a2bf647 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:d03f0153972054426d71cddc4f9617d4cf4d856a85dcc5cbe395df50231f46e3
    - SHA1:ce4661e73c9134be116d8c755afe7d5ce5135c69 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9ba8bd1b0b02ecd2f63b43f4f6be80ed [weak]
    - Filesize:122730 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 05:59:58 +0000
   Release file created at: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 10:44:06 +0000
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/by-hash/SHA256/e086d4aa81310865d65bd04e5202e1f84816cace2c9976896b047ffbb5e8ac40  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

EDIT:

Also tried: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425791/233543. No joy.

EDIT:

```
sudo wget -q -S http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release -O/dev/null
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 12:26:39 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
  Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 23:38:40 GMT
  ETag: "3ae1c-56ac8e31ec000"
  Content-Length: 241180
  Cache-Control: max-age=0, proxy-revalidate
  Expires: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 12:26:39 GMT
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: "verify there is a proxy in your path via: `wget -q -S http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/Release -O/dev/null`. If you see `X-Cache` in the output, then there is a proxy between you and `archive.ubuntu.com`." ([via](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/972077)).

Comment: The [linked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/) has lots of information and other high-rated answers and good comments, not just the accepted answer. Did you read that and what did you try from that? Probably the information for you is there, I guess you're behind a caching proxy.

Comment: I updated the question showing the output of the command. Does that indicate a proxy to you? I don't see X-Cache

Comment: You're right, that does not seem to the problem here. It might be a problem with the mirror which is not up to date ? OP in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918274/ubuntu-16-04-lts-failed-to-fetch-hash-sum-mismatch) seems to have solved same issue with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891529/software-updater-issue-16-04).

Comment: I don't think that it is the server. I have tried several. I thought the fact that this happens in Docker should somehow be a clue. I am not sure if Docker inherits the download server config from the main computer.

Comment: Not a duplicate as the other so called "duplicate" question didn't solve my problem while this one did.

Answer (score 4):

In desperation mode, I tried all of the answers to this question:

[Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error/)

One of the lowly-rated answers turned out to do the trick, namely:

https://askubuntu.com/a/809808/622128

Indeed when spinning up a Docker container, I also need to use this trick. From here on out I guess I will need Docker containers of the form

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN printf "Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth 0;\nAcquire::http::No-Cache true;\nAcquire::BrokenProxy true;" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fixbadproxy

RUN apt-get update
...
```

Without this solution, Docker can't even build the containers.

Comment: This solved it.

Comment: Confirmed for Ubuntu 23.10 as well!