# apt-get update: Signature uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, updates

when I am going to update my Ubuntu 14.04 I get following error:

> Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak
>   digest algorithm (SHA1)

(this is a plesk package)

through google I found out, that the algorithm SHA1 has been disabled since 1. January 2017.

The problem is, that the apt-get update aborts at this point, so I cannot update my other packages.

How can I solve it without reinstalling plesk?

Comment: add `--allow-insecure-repositories` at the end

Comment: Also not working `apt-get update --allow-insecure-repositories
/* Other Hits */
Hit:10 http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/LETSENCRYPT_0.0.2 xenial InRelease
Fetched 484 kB in 5s (94.7 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/LETSENCRYPT_0.0.2/dists/xenial/InRelease: Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760796/how-to-fix-apt-signature-by-key-uses-weak-digest-algorithm-sha1