# Ubuntu 20.04 desktop horrible video and mouse on Firefox

Tags: firefox, mouse, video, cpu

I have an old reliable workstation that was 16.04 until a couple weeks ago.  I upgraded to 18.04 and then after a few days to 20.04.  On both 18 and 20, video in Firefox is horrible, like 1.5 frames per sec, and the mouse is very laggy, move it across the screen and it will disappear and reappear.  None of this happened w/ 16.04.  Also, none of this occurs in other apps.  I thought I had clobbered the machine with the new OS, but I can run openshot and gimp at the same time and have no mouse/video issues.  Also, audio seems fine, Pithos plays Pandora with no issues.  Its an I3, 4 core, with 8GB RAM.

Any suggestions (beside upgrading the box!) would be appreciated.

lspci gives me:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:5912] (rev 04)
DeviceName: Onboard IGD Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd HD Graphics 630 [1458:d000] Kernel modules: i915

How do I update these, if that's what is required?

Comment: Video hardware and drivers name needed.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] accordingly. How were these "upgrades" achieved?

Comment: @24601 upgrades were achied via the checked answer in this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263794/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-20-04-in-virtual-machine

Comment: @David lspci gives me:    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:5912] (rev 04)
 DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd HD Graphics 630 [1458:d000]
 Kernel modules: i915

Comment: Boot with a live USB, and check if the problem persists there. It may be an issue with the upgrade.

Comment: Hello. @alabamatoy. I agree with Archisman. I think you need a fresh install. I3/I630 works fine in 20.04

Comment: Phooey.  Not what I wanted to hear, but I appreciate all the help.  Time to wipe and reinstall.....

Comment: Unfortunately for me, yall were right.  A fresh install and my nice video and cooperative rodent have returned.  Thanks for the help...